# Empty Repsonse Spring Data JPA + OJDBC + Spring Boot 3.1.3

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ojdbc

I am Running Oracle DB on Docker

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  oracle-db:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe
    container_name: oracle-db
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_SID=XE
      - ORACLE_PDB=XEPDB1
      - ORACLE_PWD=yourpassword
      - ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8
    volumes:
      - oracle-data:/opt/oracle/oradata

volumes:
  oracle-data:
```

and using SQL developer with success, created a new user as root

```
CREATE USER root IDENTIFIED BY password;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO root;
```

and corresponding tables with sequences as below

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    alias VARCHAR2(100),
    password VARCHAR2(50),
    email VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT emp_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE emp_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NOCACHE
    NOCYCLE;
```

Then I have these properties

```
# Database Settings
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe
    username: root
    password: password
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

  # JPA Settings
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        id:
          new_generator_mappings: false
```

Entity class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "root")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="employee_seq_generator", sequenceName="emp_seq",  allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="employee_seq_generator")
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String alias;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String email;
}
```

Repository

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

Service

```
public interface EmployeeService {

    List<Employee> findAll();
}

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService{

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> allEmployees = employeeService.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allEmployees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

When I send a request I receive empty response []

and application logs show

```
Hibernate: select e1_0.id,e1_0.alias,e1_0.email,e1_0.name,e1_0.password from root.employee e1_0
```

when I do `select * from employee;` in root schema in SQL developer, I see data is stored.

[image]

and connection settings
[image]

Comment: Is the data on SQL Developer connection actually committed? That is did you insert it and selected it from the same connection? If you don't know what I'm asking try disconnecting from SQL developer and connecting again and running that select again.

Comment: Yes I did that double checks during testing the application. I added compose file and screenshots too now

Comment: based on your screenshot you did exactly what I asked: `That is did you insert it and selected it from the same connection?` So it might be that the data you are seeing on SQL Developer is a session only. So, there, check again by running the `select * from root.employee` (notice me using the schema) and if data shows run `commit;` anyways.

Comment: Doesn't look like there is anything wrong with your app/configs so it looks like a data not committed problem

Comment: I had tried root.employee but not commit. now it worked. thank you so much. i was going mad for a day

Comment: Here take a look at this link to have a little bit better understand what is the `commit` for.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2

Comment: yeah I have been working with MySQL and Postgres and never needed or thought about commit until Oracle while I was sure I have added volume for Oracle data in docker compose so no data would be missing :) thanks again

Comment: No worries, and regarding Mysql and postgres is just that their clients or most of client implementations for those database starts with autocommit set to true. You can also do that for Oracle. But they usually don't recommend.